# What is $\theta(t)$ ? while we know that: $\ddot{\theta}(t) + 10\sin(\theta(t))-\sin(t)\cos(\theta(t))t^2+cos(t)cos(\theta(t))=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions

this is the equation I am given:

$$\ddot{\theta}(t) + 10\sin(\theta(t))-\sin(t)\cos(\theta(t))t^2+cos(t)cos(\theta(t))=0$$

Its the equation of movement of the bob of a pendulum whose pivot is moving with the function of $\sin(t)$ in a horizontal line.

And I need to know that:

$$\theta(t)=?$$

Comment: Doesn't any one have any idea?

Comment: i can't find also any solutions

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I think its because its non linear. and therefore it has no solutions. too bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you assume $\theta$ is small (similar to the regular pendulum equation), you have the linear approximation
$$ \theta'' + \omega^2\theta = t^2\sin t - \cos t $$

where $\omega^2 = 10$ as in your equation. This can be solved using standard methods.